# Is there any way to store specific value from Barcode to Excel after Barcode Scanning?

Tags: python, excel, tkinter

I've been experimenting with Barcode Scanning and I've thought of storing the barcodes I got to excel after scanning. I've been using Tkinter GUI of Python, and I've bind the entry widget to the Trigger function of the Barcode Scanner. But after reading the barcode my script enters every character of the barcode until it completes the barcode. I only want the complete barcode.
Here is my script:

```
from tkinter import*
import pandas as pd

def submit(event):
    global barcode
    if event.char in '123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-':
        barcode += event.char
        label1.config(text = barcode)
    mylist.append(entry1.get())
    path = 'excel.xlsx'
    df1 = pd.read_excel(path)
    SeriesA = df1['Number']
    A = pd.Series(barcode)
    SeriesA = SeriesA.append(A)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Number":SeriesA})
    df2.to_excel(path, index = False)
    index = df2.index
    number_of_rows = len(index)
    entry1.delete(0, END)
    print(number_of_rows)

root = Tk()

barcode = ''
mylist = []

label1 = Label(root, text = '')
label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
label2 = Label(root, text = 'Number')
label2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

entry1 = Entry(root, width = 15)
entry1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
entry1.bind('<Key>', submit)

button1 = Button(root, text = 'Quit', width = 10, command = root.quit)
button1.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
#button2 = Button(root, text = 'Submit', width = 15, command = submit)
#button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Example of what I want to barcode:
1950GSR-2USB-A

The values stored in excel would appear like this:
1

19

195

1950

1950G

1950GS

1950GSR

1950GSR-

1950GSR-2

1950GSR-2U

1950GSR-2US

1950GSR-2USB

1950GSR-2USB-

1950GSR-2USB-A

"1950GSR-2USB-A" The last one is the only data i need on my excel.
Is there any way for me to get around this?

Comment: have You tried saving the barcode to a list or sth and then append at the end

Comment: Hi, yes that was the 1st solution that came to my mind. I tried using conditional statement; if len(str(barcode)) > 13 it would append it to a list then use it. but, on my 2nd trigger of the barcode it doesnt reset and concatenates the next barcode from the previous one.

Comment: how about when writing the barcode to the file after that You make the list empty? like `lst = []`